# Apps broken after Monterey 12.3 update

Tags: python, monterey, rosetta

After having updated macOS to Monterey 12.3 a number of programs or apps are failing to work. For example, when trying to run perl I obtain

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/perl: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Same thing when trying to run python:

```
-bash: /Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/python: Bad CPU type in executable
```

A number of Apps downloaded from the Mac App Store also do not work and return a laconic "Unable to check for updates, please check your internet connection and try again" window (I am, of course, connected to the internet).

Thinking that this problem might be related to Rosetta I have tried updating,

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

to no avail. I got the following as a response

```
Rosetta 2 update is not available
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5826458) did the trick:

> - Go to your Library folder > Preferences and find this file:
>   com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
> - Delete it.
> - Locate and delete the same file in your user Library folder.
>   Restart your Mac and OS X should generate new files that point the software update service back to Apple's servers.

Comment: Did you then install rosetta to fix the issues reported in the post?